# Vite React: import css from node_modules

Tags: vite

Here's my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
// import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles';
// import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    // postcss(),
    // styles(),
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: ['.css'],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    // outDir: '../../static/campaign/js',
    outDir: '../../../../static/campaign/js', // Directly into Django's static dir
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `image-uploader/assets/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `image-uploader/assets/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `image-uploader/assets/[name].[ext]`,
      },
    },
    sourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

I've tried both `styles()` and `postcss()` and each of them are giving me a `css-syntax-error`.

I'm simply trying to `import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';` at my `App.jsx`.

PostCSS gives me:

```
▲ [WARNING] Unexpected "=" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:1:13:
      1 │ var css_248z = "/*!\n * Cropper.js v1.6.1\n * https://fengyuanchen....
```

and Styles gives me:

```
▲ [WARNING] Unexpected ";" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:3:25:
      3 │ var modules_3585addf = {};
```

Even if i copy the css file into my app and load it from within src, i'm not seeing that file in my Sources or anything once I build. Is my vite config not set up properly to import css?